# Slow runtime in c++ for basic program

Tags: c++

I am doing a problem where you read input from a file (two strings, at most 6 letters in all caps). The characters are then converted to ascii and shifted so that "A" is denoted by 1, and "Z" by 26. The product of these numbers is then calculated. The products of these two strings are then checked for equivalency (mod 47). If they are equivalent, "GO" is output to a file. If they aren't equivalent "STAY" is output. The program runs and yields the desired output, but takes over 1 second to run when it shouldn't be taking that long. Can anyone tell me why the runtime is > 1 second?

Here is my code, it's not too long:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ofstream fout ("ride.out"); //create files
  ifstream fin ("ride.in");
  string cometName, groupName; //initialize vars
  fin >> cometName >> groupName;
  fin.close();
  int cometSum = 1;
  int groupSum = 1;
  int & cometSumAlias = cometSum;
  int & groupSumAlias = groupSum;

  for (char & c : cometName) {//iterate through strings and multiply chars
    cometSumAlias *= (c - 64);
  }
  for (char & c : groupName) {
    groupSumAlias *= (c - 64);
  }

  if (cometSumAlias % 47 == groupSumAlias % 47) {//equivalency check
    fout << "GO" << endl; //output to file
  } else {
    fout << "STAY" << endl;
  }
  fout.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compilation options?

Comment: You'd be surprised to learn how much work has to be done in order to load and execute a process. Especially on certain technically obsolete operating systems \*cough\*. A second of CPU time to get everything squared away is not unreasonable.

Comment: How are you timing that it takes more than a second?

Comment: Try using fscanf

Comment: Are you running the release or the debug version of the program? Do you launch the program from the IDE or do you launch the .exe file directly (say from Explorer or a command prompt)?

Comment: Your program runs almost instantly when I try it. Try compiling and running the program `int main() { return 0; }` and see if it's that slow.

Comment: What is significant about the numbers 64 and 47?  I recommend using character literals instead of decimal ASCII values.  Also, use named constants instead of *magic* numbers.

Comment: Don't use `fscanf`. The magic that makes it work makes `fscanf` stupidly easy to screw up compared to `>>` for very little gain. Profile the code to find the slowdown. If data in is your villain, [turn off the stdio synchronization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) and see if that helps.

Comment: I am doing problems on the USACO training site. The site says the program is taking >1 second to run. I myself am using a g++ compiler to run it but am not sure how USACO compiles the program. I am just using atom and then launching from the terminal.